# return 403 response for custom path in Ambassador

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, ambassador

we are running a Kubernetes cluster managed with Terraform. For routing external traffic to our services we use Ambassador (https://www.getambassador.io/). We would like to have one specific endpoint to be accessible only from the internal network. Do anyone knows best practice to achieve it with Ambassador?

I thought about forcing Ambassador to return 403 response for that path, but couldn't find the proper way to do it with Ambassador. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can ip whitelist your local ip-range. https://blog.getambassador.io/ip-allow-deny-on-kubernetes-customizable-rate-limit-responses-8c6d4792a647

Comment: I don't see an option to specify only the single path here, but thanks for pointing this out.